# Passing an array object through generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to pass an object array, but I kept on getting errors.  For example, I am trying to pass a Faculty object array, but how would I call it on main?

```
//main code

Faculty[] g = new Faculty[2];

g[0]= new Faculty ("Johnson", "Anne", 243, 'F',62,4,27, "FU","Ph.D", "Engineering",3);
g[1]= new Faculty ("Wu", "John", 243, 'F',62,4,27, "FU", "Ph.D", "Engineering", 3);


//I tried the following two lines and it gave me an error

BinarySearch<Object>  eOb =  new BinarySearch<>(g);

BinarySearch<Faculty> eOb =  new BinarySearch<>(g);
```

This is how I declared my Binary Search class with generics

```
public class BinarySearch <T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private T[] array;

    public BinarySearch( T[] a){
        super();
        array = a;
    }

    public int binarySearch(T number){
        // Code

    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> Bound mismatch: The type Object is not a valid substitute for the
>   bounded parameter > of the type
>   BinarySearch - T cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: "I'm getting errors" - and they are...?

Comment: Bound mismatch: The type Object is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<T>> of the type 
  BinarySearch<T>
 - T cannot be resolved to a type

Answer (score 1):

So long as `Faculty` is declared as:

```
public class Faculty implements Comparable<Faculty> {

}
```

...the second form should suffice:

```
BinarySearch<Faculty> eOb =  new BinarySearch<>(g);
```

`Object` isn't a `Comparable` and so it cannot fall in the bounds of one.

Comment: I have exactly what you have, it still gives me an error.  It gives me an error of:Multiple markers at this line
 - Faculty is a raw type. References to generic type Faculty<T> should be parameterized
 - Bound mismatch: The type Faculty is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T 
  extends Comparable<T>> of the type BinarySearch<T>

Comment: Did you get rid of the `BinarySearch<Object>` declaration?  As I explained above, since `Object` isn't a `Comparable`, that form will not work.  Also, are you sure that you're actually using the type for the array?  Are you **sure** that `Faculty implements Comparable<Faculty>`?